# How to add segments to AVPlayer asset?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a local mp3 audio file that I would like to break up into segments or chapters. I wanted to present all the segments in a list and highlight which segmented is currently playing.

This is what I'm trying:

```swift
let asset = AVAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(...)!)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

let meta1 = AVMutableMetadataItem()
meta1.key = AVMetadataKey.quickTimeUserDataKeyChapter as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
meta1.value = "Chapter 1" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol

let start1 = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1)
let end1 = CMTime(seconds: 3, preferredTimescale: 1)
let range1 = CMTimeRange(start: start1, end: end1)
let segment1 = AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: [meta1], timeRange: range1)

let meta2 = AVMutableMetadataItem()
meta2.key = AVMetadataKey.quickTimeUserDataKeyChapter as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
meta2.value = "Chapter 2" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol

let start2 = CMTime(seconds: 3, preferredTimescale: 1)
let end2 = CMTime(seconds: 8, preferredTimescale: 1)
let range2 = CMTimeRange(start: start2, end: end2)
let segment2 = AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: [meta2], timeRange: range1)

// TODO: Add segments to asset

let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

How do I associated the `AVTimedMetadataGroup` object to my `AVPlayerItem`? Is this the correct approach?

Comment: AVQueuePlayer is best to use segments.

Comment: I tried asking about that but it's not clear how to use that either :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101965/how-to-use-avcomposition-instead-of-avqueueplayer